# No shares on ghash.io and no payout — how to resolve this?

Tags: mining-pools, mining-profitability, ghash.io

Been mining with ghash.io for a few hours at about 80Gh/s.  However, I apparently have no shares and therefore am not receiving any payout.  Is this an issue with my setup?  How can I resolve this?

Comment: http://www.coindesk.com/bitcoin-miners-ditch-ghash-io-pool-51-attack/

Answer (score 0):

Most pools update users' balances in several hours, so I advise you to find an alternative bitcoin pool -- there are lots of them, and also write to ghash.io support.

P.S. maybe you were not mining? You should have received *yay!!!* messages in your miner console.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue but at the end it showed up that i needed to wait 3 hours for my shares to show up. Probably your shares will show up in couple hours too.